# Shortcut or symlink within OneDrive

Tags: symbolic-link, onedrive, mklink, file-shortcut

Is it possible on Microsoft OneDrive 2018 to have either a shortcut or a symlink (e.g. made using `mklink`) to another folder within the same OneDrive sync? Specifically, is this possible:

```
OneDrive
├╴ folder1
│  └╴ subfolder1a
└╴ folder2
   └╴ subfolder1a -> ..\folder1\subfolder1a
```

Where `folder2\subfolder1a` is really just a symlink (of some sort) to `folder2\..\folder1\subfolder1a`?

Using a standard shortcut (`.lnk`) doesn't seem to work, since it binds the shortcut to my full local path (`C:\Users\villapx\OneDrive\folder1\subfolder1a`), and that's not sufficient since it's my organization's OneDrive, and so the other users of this folder obviously don't have my same username and folder structure.

I also tried using `mklink` to make a symbolic link, which works locally on my machine, but the symlink doesn't seem to be uploading to OneDrive, so I wonder if it's not supported. It's been showing as "Status: sync pending" for the past 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

This is (sort of) possible. Though instead of creating a *link*, you'll actually be duplicating the files you want to store in both locations. For this use `mklink /J Destination Source` to create a junction.

I am not sure if this is the way you want it. (I was also looking for something different but may as well answer your question). This might also not sync changes properly when you are working in OneDrive online.

Btw credit to [chuckbales](https://www.reddit.com/user/chuckbales/) over on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/8zxeol/do_symbolic_links_still_work_with_onedrive_i_need/)

Comment: Ah, unfortunately (Wikipedia says) junction links only support absolute paths, not relative paths. So this would give me the same issue as with a `.lnk` shortcut

Comment: @villapx Ok, then we are both looking for a solution here. I got the same issue myself and have used this "workaround". That's fine in my case because no one else has access to that specific folder, but still. Even Google Drive has that feature...